# Oracle SQL - 1 input for 2 arguments

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I used 1 input e.g. **&parm** for 2 arguments?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_01
WHERE col_1 = &parm AND col_2 = &parm;
```

When I executed, SQL developer need enter 2 arguments. I want that `col_1` and `col_2` enter one input **&parm**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double ampersand (&&). Please take a look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia#2_4)